# C: segmentation fault when running function from another file

Tags: c

When ever i run this code, it works up until i get to the printf statement in my main function, thats when i get a segmentation fault error. so it will run like  "enter how many numbers you want"   3   "Enter the numbers in the array"  1 2 3  array[0] = 1 array[1] = 2 array[2] = 3  segmentation error.  Can you guys please tell me why im getting this error and how to fix it? thank you

```
//pathfinder.c    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Vector.h"

int main()
{
    Vector *V;
    VectorRead(V);
    printf("%d", V->item[0]);
    return 0;
}

//Vector.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
typedef struct{
int *item;
int size;
} Vector;

void VectorRead(Vector *V) ;

void VectorRead(Vector *V)
{
    int N;
    printf("Enter how many numbers you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    V = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector *) * N);
    V->size = N;
    V->item = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *) * V->size);
    printf("Enter the numbers that you want in your array\n");
    int i = 0;
    while(i < V->size && scanf("%d", &(V->item[i++])) == 1);
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j< V->size; j++){
            printf("array[%d]=%d\n", j, V->item[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: C is pass-by-value. Changing a parameter in a function doesn't affect the argument in the caller.

Comment: ...but if you pass the address of the parameter as a pointer, you can change the value targeted by this pointer.

Comment: @peterh: ...or you could do the sane thing and `return` a pointer.

Comment: @EOF Btw, the beautifulness of the C is its dirtyness. :-) Yes, C is _mainly_ pass-by-value, but arrays are passed by address. There is no rule in C without exceptions :-) Well, it was named after the next step after BCPL, but actually it abbreviates to me _C_haos :-)

Comment: @peterh: No. C11 draft standard `6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators Section 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.` This has nothing to do with call-by-reference or "pass by address".

Comment: @EOF Your whole citate hasn't to do anything to this problem. I would suggest to use googling and C snippets, instead of digging standards and other papers from different committees. You are already the 2345345245. standard-citator I meet here on the SO, and honestly, you can't even imagine, how boring is it :-)

Comment: @peterh: On the contrary. You are simply wrong about there being anything special about using an array as an argument to a function. Function call is *not* inconsistent. It's arrays that have strange semantics in c.

Comment: @EOF Yes, that is true. :-(

Comment: You malloc the wrong number of bytes in both malloc calls. This could be avoided by using the pattern `p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );`

Comment: You check the result of `scanf` but then you go on to print every entry in the array even if the scanning failed

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with your code being in different files.

When you call `VectorRead()`, you are passing a pointer value. Inside that function, you are setting the *local* `V` to the return value of a call to `malloc()`. There is no way for that local `V` to return back to the caller.

You will need to do something to return the newly allocated value of `V` back to the caller. Changing your function to return a `Vector *` (instead of taking one as a parameter) would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your local `Vector`, `V`, is not being modified when `VectorRead()` is called. Try instead accepting a `Vector **` in your function:

```
void VectorRead(Vector **V)
```

and modify the function accordingly.

Or, since your function has no return value, and as @EOF points out in the comments, it is probably a better idea to *not* take a parameter, and simply return the `Vector *`:

```
Vector *VectorRead(void)
```

Comment: Why does everyone want to get people to use multiple indirection? Just `return` the damn pointer!

Comment: That is an option. However, it may be safer in some situations, instead of simply returning, or if a different return value is needed, etc.

Comment: Given that the OP's function is `void`, changing it to return a `Vector *` doesn't seem terribly difficult.

Comment: `Vector *VectorRead(void)`; would be better, as that is a prototype.